# All files missing from Git, Frameworks gone from Project Navigator

Tags: xcode, git, xcode7

I was attempting to add a remote repository to my already in progress project. In the process of doing so all my files disappeared from the Commit section of Source Control (Using Git)

[image]

Also, all of the Frameworks that I downloaded from the internet (specifically my Parse Frameworks) disappeared from Finder and appeared red in the navigator.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this? I attempted to "Discard all Changes..." which proved to do nothing, and I tried dragging in newly downloaded frameworks, which also did not work. Should I just make a new project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your frameworks folder got nuked/moved.

Without more info, this is my generic advice: first make a copy of the directory which encapsulates your git repo. Then look into the git commands `git reset` and the big hammer `git reflog`. Good luck.

Comment: restored to previous time machine backup, will accept this answer because it is what I would have done if it were not for time machine.